# I cannot fix the error "Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render."

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I believe I understand what the issue is (the inputs I'm trying to v-model aren't declared), but I can't seem to fix it (or understand how to) even after reading the other posts with the same problem.

I also compared the code to the tutorial's I was following, and I can't spot any differences, or at least none that should lead to this error in specific.

I have two files, Index.js;

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);
// GITHUBAPI
import GitHubAPI from 'vue-github-api';
Vue.use(GitHubAPI, {token: 'user Personal Access Token'});
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import GitIssuesAndMiles from './app/IssuesAndMilestones.vue';
import './index.scss';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        data: {
        },
        default: GitIssuesAndMiles
      }
    }
  ]
});
export default new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
  },
  router,
  render: h => h('router-view')
});
```

And IssuesAndMilestones.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container id="app">
        <v-layout align-center justify-space-around fill-height/>
            <v-flex xs12 text-xs-center>
                <h1>Vue/GitHub</h1>
            </v-flex>
            <!-- Here starts the area where the user would write the GitHub information-->
            <v-flex v-flex xs4 offset-xs4>
                        <input 
                        v-model="_usernameVMod" 
                        type="text" 
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Usuário">

                        <input 
                        v-model="_repoVMod" 
                        type="text" 
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Repositório">          
            </v-flex>
            <!-- Here ends the area where the user would write the GitHub information-->
            <v-flex xs4 offset-xs4 row justify-center>              
                <v-btn large color="green lighten-2">Search</v-btn>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                _usernameVMod: '',
                _repoVMod: '',
            };
        },
        methods:{},

    };
</script>
```

Comment: you must be getting the property name with the error, can you post the error as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in Router constructor. Route configuration is wrong. Try with this config

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: GitIssuesAndMiles },
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to figure out the error. Apparently Vue just really hates it when you name something starting with "_". When I changed the names from "_usernameVMod" to "usernameVMod" the code started flowing. Even so, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So if anyone else has a similar problem, I managed to fix it.

It seems Vue just really hates it when you name something starting with "_", so when I changed the names from "_usernameVMod" to "usernameVMod" the code started flowing.